# Collect all VersionOne assets and all their attributes using Java

Tags: java, versionone

I'm working on a task that requires me to export all assets and all their attribute values into a CSV file. I know that there is an option to export into Excel, but that one has its problems and we decide to give a chance to an API.

The problem I faced is that while I can get all assets of a specific type with the code

```
IServices services = new Services(connector);
IAssetType requestType = services.getMeta().getAssetType("Request");
Query query = new Query(requestType);
```

it isn't clean how to return **all** asset's attributes. There is a `getAttributes()` for the `Asset` object

```
QueryResult result = services.retrieve(query);

for (Asset asset : result.getAssets()) {
    Map<String, Attribute> attributes = asset.getAttributes();
    System.out.println(attributes.toString());
}
```

but it doesn't seem to return an attribute unless it is explicitly added into a query eg.

```
…

Query query = new Query(requestType);

IAttributeDefinition nameAttribute = requestType.getAttributeDefinition("Name");
IAttributeDefinition numberAttribute = requestType.getAttributeDefinition("Number");
query.getSelection().add(nameAttribute);
query.getSelection().add(numberAttribute);

QueryResult result = services.retrieve(query);

…
```

which doesn't make sense to me, since I may not even know all possible object's attributes!

I feel like `getAttributes()` method may not be suitable for this purpose, but what else to use then? Any ideas on how I can collect the data I need?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Meta API query to [retrieve metadata for specific asset type](https://community.versionone.com/VersionOne_Connect/Developer_Library/Learn_the_API/Meta_API/Retrieve_metadata_for_a_specific_asset_type):

```
<Server Base URI>/meta.v1/Request
```

Answer (score 0):

In general VersionOne APIs don't return all available attributes at once as a default. When using the VersionOne Rest api, the most important subset of attributes are returned and no custom fields. The VersionOne sdks are a wrapper around this api so it stands to reason that api business rules are fulfilled in the sdk.  You will have to know the names of all possible attributes of an asset and explicitly request them. This includes custom fields `(Custom_AttributeName)`. This can be queried by doing a [meta query](https://community.versionone.com/VersionOne/VersionOne_Basics/Common_Questions/How_do_I_find_my_meta%3F) `YourVersionOneInstance/meta.v1/YourAssetName`.  You then will have to iterate through this xml tree and get the attribute names and wrap the proper query plumbing around each attribute.